# Resource responses is cut

Tags: javascript, html, response

I have a web app which displays a Java Script image carousel. 
Showing one image at a time for *n* seconds.

When the html page (index.html) loads it loads all *n* images in an hidden parent html DIV and the app (JavaScript) is responsible for showing and hiding the parent divs for the images at a given interval.

This usually works fine, but some times (randomly) only half of the image is loaded (eg. just half of the image is displayed on the screen).

Sometimes only "half" of the index.html response is loaded making the HTML kode to bleed out to the display.
Unfortunatly I do not have any tools like Firebug etc. to debug the problem yet since the screen is a kiosk (screen hanging on the wall)

To me this seems like a network problem but I am no network administrator so I will just be guessing here.

As I said this happens randomly.

The image starts loading but only half of the image. Sometimes after maybe 15 seconds the rest of the image is suddenly displayed.

If this could be a network problem the what could it be?

Best regards, 
bob

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a network issue. Why not try and cache the images on the browser so you don't have to wait for them to load every time. Also try looking in the Firebug/Web Inspector Net panel and you should be able to see if the browser is waiting on a network response or not.